# UEFI Installation Ubuntu parallel to Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, 16.04, windows-10

I follow all the common instructions. I installed Ubuntu through disabling the UEFI block and uneabling the USB boot.
When I restart the pc, with the legacy options enabled, I have the following message:

> the is no boot loader available

What I have to do to recognize the presence of both UBUNTU and Windows? Enable again the UEFI protocol?
I also tryed to install through inside the live try of UBUNTU but it doesn't recognize the presence of Windows.

Comment: ***DO NOT*** enable the Compatibility Support Module (CSM) or "disable the UEFI." (Technically, you can't do the latter, but that takes a long explanation.) See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) and [the Ubuntu community wiki entry on UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) for advice on installing Ubuntu in EFI mode. Note that if you're having problems booting the installer, chances are it's not been properly prepared, as noted on my page. You can work around this by enabling BIOS mode, but that just creates bigger problems later.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a advantage to install ubuntu in uefi mode.
Turn off the legacy mode. If you might be able to boot into Windows 10 you can make ubuntu by Using  [win32 disk imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/)

And make bootable usb drive and then install ubuntu. 
remember one thing in new Laptop if after installing Ubuntu the system may default loads into Windows. So either you can go into bios to select the boot order. The Ubuntu is displayed as seperated disk. Or Press boot menu button in the starting of your pc and select boot order as you are doing in case of selecting your usb drive.